# How to set multi-level x-axis in echarts?

Tags: echarts

I am building a chart with dates as the x-axis and we use Baidu echarts to build them.

For a range of 10-15 days, I just plot them via xAxis.data and it works. But when I have a bigger range, say of 2-3 months, the dates come up stacked or too crunched for space as there are many of them. After looking at some ideas on the web, I was thinking of formating them as below(The days are grouped by months and seperated at a uniform gap of 8-10 days):

```
2    12    22    2    12    22    2    12    22
     Dec               Jan             Feb
```

I am aware of the *xAxis.axisLabel.formatter* but that seems to be helpful when I want to format individual entry, not what I want. Is it possible in echarts to have a multi-level x-axis where top is individual entries & bottom row basically represents group for them?

Hope it made sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example: https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xBk7TY_hWx

Generally speaking, you need to create an extra entry in `xAxis` (or `yAxis` in the example's case) and another series like:

```
{
    type: 'bar',
    data:['-', '-', '-', '-', '-'],
    yAxisIndex: 2
}
```

Comment: Yeah the example you shared looks promising. Please gimme a day to try this out and I'll get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For more general implementation of the grouped category axis, hope this example is helpful to you.

https://jsfiddle.net/borguenon/kyj2pxhz/13/

```
    xAxis: [
    {
        position: "bottom",
        data: ["shirt","cardign","chiffon shirt","pants","heels","socks"]
    },
    {
        position: "bottom",
        data: ["group1", "", "", "group2", "", ""],
      interval: 1,
      axisLine: {
        show: false
      },
      axisTick: {
        alignWithLabel: false,
        length: 40,
        align: "left",
        interval: function(index, value) {
          return value ? true : false;
        }
      },
      axisLabel: {
        margin: 30
      },
      splitLine: {
        show: true,
        interval: function(index, value) {
          return value ? true : false;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

[Grouped category axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2l3p.png)